# How do I tell VLC to start to play a file at a certain point in time when that time is a variable?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, vlc, timedelay

I am trying to invoke 
    vlc --start-time=$x filename.mp3 
but the file begins to play from the beginning.

I use

```
    echo "give me the time"
    read x
```

to assign a value to $x. Then I subtract 3 to start playing the file a bit earlier than that.

I wonder if $x needs to have a specific format. 
I tried

```
    ((x=$x-3))
```

and also

```
    x=`echo $x-3|bc -l`
```

and also several variations of "" '' `` () around $x e.g. like so

```
    vlc --start-time="$x" filename
    vlc '--start-time="$x"' filename
```

but none of that works. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I hope it helps

```
 "vlc --start-time=$(($x-3)) filename"
```

Comment: Ashes on my head!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Nguyen!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nguyen!

Ashes on my head, I invoked the wrong file! 
Both versions work, mine

```
    "vlc --start-time=$x filename"
```

and yours

```
    "vlc --start-time=$(($x-3)) filename"
```

Sorry for the confusion!